# aureliajs conditional parent layout

Tags: module, render, aurelia

I am writing my client app in aureliajs. And by default, for a route like this:

```
/app/access/management
```

my app gets rendered like this:

[image: rendering schema]

For example assume that the header and sidebar gets rendered on `app` and then a common container in `access` and finally the main html in `management`.

Now I have a sub-component of `access` for example with name `list`. And in this component I want the page being rendered without any parent container (without parent html tags).

So I think I have some solutions:

1. Making the `list` in another module for example `/app1/access/list` which does not render any additional html on app1 and access.
2. Make a condition inside `app` and `access` to decide drawing the header and footer and etc.
3. Call a function in `list` to hide the drawn layout in parents.

But I can't find the best way. For example a way to tell the parent not render something.

What is the best practice or pattern?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Similar to MVC-style master/layout pages, Aurelia allows you to use a
>   "layout" view like an MVC "master template" for a set of views.
>
> The set of views subject to being part of a layout is defined in
>   Aurelia as a set of views referenced by one or more routes in a router
>   configuration. There are two ways to associate a layout with routes.
>   The first is via HTML, the second is via view model code. ...

and

> ... To specify a layout on the router-view custom element, we use the
>   following attributes:
>
> - layout-view - specifies the file name (with path) of the layout view to use.
> - layout-view-model - specifies the moduleId of the view model to use with the layout view.
> - layout-model - specifies the model parameter to pass to the layout view model's activate function. ...

and then via route config:

> ... We can also associate layouts with route configurations using code in
>   our view model. Suppose we like what we've done above, but we have a
>   couple views that we would like to associate with a different layout
>   and would thus like to partially override the configuration given in
>   the HTML. The following code is an example of how we can do that:
>   ...

I suggest you read this article carefully: [aurelia router configuration --> Layouts](https://aurelia.io/docs/routing/configuration#layouts)

Comment: combining usage of layouts and sub routes put me into trouble but finally I have solved it some way. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a condition if `access component` ViewModel to check if route was `/app/access/list`, then component load with container less property.

Comment: Thanks Mohammad. Omid's answer solved my issue. I think it is a more suitable solution although yours does.